# Bootstrap navbar grows vertically during resize, can this be prevented?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When my browser is resized smaller, the bootstrap navbar starts dropping the list items vertically before collapsing.  I really just want them to collapse when they run out of horizontal space.  Is there a way to force this to happen?  I have a sample at [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/KIhkkXScxm).

Comment: Not without custom CSS. See also the "Overflowing content" box in the Navbar docs.

Comment: That is the exact situation, thanks for pointing me to it.  Put this in as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without custom(ized) CSS. [The documentation explicitly addresses your situation:](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

> ### Overflowing content
>
> Since Bootstrap doesn't know how much space the content in your navbar needs, you might run into issues with content wrapping into a second row. To resolve this, you can:
>
> a. Reduce the amount or width of navbar items.
>   b. Hide certain navbar items at certain screen sizes using [responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).
>   c. Change the point at which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal mode. Customize the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable or add your own media query.